# Ubuntu's appindicator using QML

Tags: indicator, qml

Is it possible to create a Unity indicator for my app which is written in QML?

Comment: Are you talking about ActivityIndicators - [Building your first App](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/building-your-first-qml-app/)?

Comment: @Symsymmas No it's not what I'm searching for. The `ActivityIndicator` used there is an animated gif which is inside the app window and it's shown while the app fetches some data from internet. My goal is to have an icon near the clock on the top-right of the whole screen.